# Why is file I'm saving gpg --verify's output to staying empty?

Tags: command-line, gnupg

When I run `gpg --version > Desktop\op.txt` command in command prompt, it creates an `op.txt` file on desktop with contents of the `gpg` version.

But when I run `gpg --verify path\of\.asc\file > Desktop\op.txt`, It creates a blank `op.txt` file on Desktop.

Output of `gpg --verify path\of\.asc\file` is

```
gpg: Signature made 06/16/14 20:34:29 India Standard Time using RSA key ID 7590DAFD
gpg: Good signature from "user"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg: There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner. Primary key fingerprint: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

I was expecting this output in `op.txt`, but `op.txt` is blank.

Why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GnuPG prints (at least some of) this output to stderr, not stdout. Redirect stderr to stdout using `2>&1`:

```
gpg --verify path\of\.asc\file 2>&1 > Desktop\op.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. the following worked for me `gpg --verify path\of\.asc\file > Desktop\op.txt 2>&1`